# Is there any pre-defined exception type that serves as a container for a list of exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

When throwing an exception based upon catching another exception, the latter exception can be passed along in the [`InnerException` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=netframework-4.7.2).

I am executing a number of clean-up routines. Even if one of them fails, I would like to run all of them (because they may need to tidy up temporarily saved data).

At the same time, I do not want to swallow the exceptions that might arise during the execution of the clean-up methods.

A straightforward solution would be to wrap each clean-up call in a `try`-`catch` block and adding any caught exception into a list. After executing all of the clean-up methods, if there was at least one exception, I could then still throw ... something:

```
var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
foreach (var handler in handlers)
{
    try
    {
        handler.CleanUp();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Add(ex);
    }
}
if (exceptions.Count > 0)
{
    throw ...
}
```

Now, my question is: **Is there anything pre-defined in the BCL that I can throw here and that propagates all the caught exceptions?**

I am thinking of an exception that has something like an `InnerExceptions` property that holds more than one exception. (Or is there a different pattern that should be applied in this case?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`System.AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netframework-4.7.2).  And it has exactly that, [InnerExceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_AggregateException_InnerExceptions).  You can add the collection of inner exceptions in one of its constructors, [like this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_AggregateException__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Exception__).

Comment: Excellent! It's so easy to find ... if one just thinks of the right vocabulary ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)

So in your case you can do like below using one of the overloaded constructor `AggregateException(IEnumerable<Exception>)`

```
if (exceptions.Count > 0)
{
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions)
}
```

Comment: [rory.ap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53742922/1430156) was slightly faster (and both of the answers are equally helpful ... so I'm going to accept theirs, and upvote yours.